# How does the clan/titans system work?

Tags: clicker-heroes

The latest (0.20) update added *clans* to the game. Every day, the clan can battle *titans* for hero souls.

I started a clan for me and my friends, and then killed a few titans. Reward: 6 hero souls. This seems very little, considering I can usually make a few 100'000 souls per hour farming (and the 50 rubies I spent on creating the clan would have given me 1.2 million souls).

Do the rewards ramp up? What is the benefit of being in a clan? How do we cooperate to fight titans?

In general, what is the new clan system, and how can we make use of it?